# Корень квадратного уравнения, правильный try { } catch { }

Tags: java

Всем, привет! Помогите пожалуйста новичку в JAVA!

Я составил скрипт вычисления корня квадратного уравнения, но как известно *Квадратное уравнение* — это уравнение вида **ax^2 + bx + c = 0**, где коэффициенты **a**, **b** и **c** — произвольные числа, причем **a ≠ 0**.

Так вот как корректно сформировать *try { } catch { }* для условия **a ≠ 0**.
Понятное дело что это можно сделать через *if ( ) { } else { }*, но как новичку хотелось бы понять как сделать через *try { } catch { }*.

---

**Мое решение уравнения:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        // Моя кривая реализация try { } catch { }
        /*try {      
            out.printf("Введите число a (a ≠ 0) - ");
            int a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            out.printf("Число a должно быть ≠ 0 - ");
            int a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        }*/

        out.printf("Введите число a (a ≠ 0) - ");
            int a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        out.printf("Введите число b - ");
            int b = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        out.printf("Введите число c - ");
            int c = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        int D = b*b-(4*a*c);

        if(D < 0)
        {
            out.println("Корней нет! Ничего считать не надо!");
        }
        else if (D == 0)
        {
            out.println("Есть ровно один корень!");

            double d = Math.sqrt(D);

            double x = (-b+d)/2*a;

            out.printf("И мы его нашли x = %s", x);
        }
        else if(D > 0)
        {
            out.println("Корней будет два!");

            double d = Math.sqrt(D);

            double x1 = (-b+d)/2*a;
                int i1 = (int) x1;
            double x2 = (-b-d)/2*a;
                int i2 = (int) x2;

            out.printf("И мы их нашли x(1) = %s и x(2) = %s", i1, i2);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, смысл вычисления корня из нуля:


    else if (D == 0)
        {    
        double d = Math.sqrt(D);

        double x = (-b+d)/2*a;

Comment: @knes очевидно это просто последствия копипаста - логика в этой ветке и в последующей выглядят похожими

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще в данной задаче довольно сомнительна необходимость отлавливать подобные ошибки с помощью исключений. Но если очень очется, то можно сделать например так (с java не особо знаком, поэтому пишу на некоем псевдо-java):

```
try {
    ....
    double x = (-b+d)/2*a;
}
catch(DivisionByZeroException e) {
    out.printf("a не может быть равным нулю!");
}
```

Либо даже так: при вводе коэффициента можете проверить его на равенство нулю, а затем, в случае истинности условия, выкинуть исключение, а потом отловить его в блоке catch. Причем, этот вариант предпочтительнее. Пример:

```
try {      
    ... 
    if(a == 0)
        throw new SomeTerribleException();
} 
catch(SomeTerribleException e) {
    out.printf("a не может быть равным нулю!");
}
catch () {
    ....
}
```

Comment: в смысле до ввода? мысли читать что ли?

Comment: @Артёмыч до ввода? Это как?

Comment: @Артёмыч ну так объясните по-русски, что вы хотите? Пока что не особо понятно

Comment: рассказываю, как только программа говорит пользователю "Введите число a (a ≠ 0) - ", а он умышленно вводит 0, программа понимает что это ошибка и формирует новое сообщение "Число a должно быть ≠ 0 попробуйте еще раз - "

Comment: @DreamChild разве это до ввода отработает??? сомневаюсь... но спасибо за ответ :)

Comment: @Артёмыч это не отработает до ввода, однако так и не должно быть.  Как вообще по-вашему программа может понять, ошибочны ли введённые данные, если вы ещё ничего не ввели? Постарайтесь рассуждать  логически

Comment: @DreamChild рассуждаю логически: Пользователь получил сообщение на экран "Введите число a (a ≠ 0) - ", но пользователь решил посмотреть что будет если введу a = 0, как только пользователь ввел значение a = 0, вот сюда *int a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());* сохранили значение!, напрашивается вопрос: А, что нельзя проверить что лежит в *int a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());* сразу после ввода?

Comment: @Артёмыч вы сами себе противоречите. Сначала вы говорите 

>а вот ДО ввода коэффициента хотелось бы

>разве это ДО ввода отработает???

теперь же пишете 

>А, что нельзя проверить сразу ПОСЛЕ ввода?

Поэтому я еще раз призываю вас рассуждать логически. 

На всякий случай снова повторю: до ввода коэффициента ничего сделать нельзя, поскольку телепатия человечеством пока ещё не изобретена. После ввода сделать можно, и именно это описано в моем ответе, в его второй части.

Comment: @DreamChild воооот, теперь второй ответ я вижу, спасибо :)

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю как-то так

```
out.printf("Введите число a (a ≠ 0) - ");
boolean check = false;
while (check == false){
    try {      
        int a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        check = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        out.printf("Число a должно быть ≠ 0 - ");
        out.printf("Введите еще раз");
    }
}
```

Comment: я могу ошибаться, но по-моему вы здесь не страхуетесь от нуля

Comment: ну я только конструкцию с try catch предложил. Логика решения уравнения уже не так важна

Comment: @cadmy спасибо, за ответ

Comment: IOException ? Вы что значения из файла читаете?
В данном случае нужен ArithmeticException.